# Listing projected coordinate systems using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, coordinate-system

How can I get complete list of projected coordinate systems available in ArcGIS using Python?

I have this set of coordinates in China:
`121°27'32.681"E, 29°56'26.03"N`

Which correspond to approximately to
`594520, 116410` in unknown system

I am struggling to find the projection.

So I thought of using to brute force approach, but I need access to list of projections.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can be done using ArcPy's [ListSpatialReferences](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-functions/listspatialreferences.htm) which:

> Returns a Python list of available spatial reference names for use as
>   an argument to arcpy.SpatialReference.